# Using VLOOKUP() to compare and filter two columns in different worksheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

When I filter a column using `VLOOKUP()` between two worksheets, how can I also filter all of its respective row elements too? Maybe this will help illustrate my question.

I have two worksheets:

***Sample0.xlsx***

[image]

***Sample1.xlsx***

[image]

I want to filter the items that are in the **New list** column of Sample1.xlsx but *are not* in the **Old List** column of Sample0.xlsx. And have its respective matching **Type** row elements also filtered along with it.

I'm using the following `VLOOKUP()` formula:

```
=FILTER(A2:A15,ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A15,[Sample0.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$15,1,FALSE)))
```

And I get these results:

[image]

How can I also filter the Type column that goes along with the New List column that  I just filtered out? I hope it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Found this (https://blog.coupler.io/excel-vlookup-multiple-columns/) on google, might be what you need.  Looks like you can use curly braces to specify multiple columns to carry over.

Comment: `=FILTER(A2:A15,ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A15&"|"&B2:B15,[Sample0.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$15&"|"&[Sample0.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15,,1,0)))`

Comment: I tried with the curly brackets ```=FILTER(A2:A15,ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A15,[Sample0.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$15,{1,2},FALSE)))``` but unfortunately it isn't working.

Comment: P.B your formula doesn't work, it's returning an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of FILTER() describes what column(s) you want to *return*, irrespective of what columns you want to *match*.  Your formula `=FILTER(A2:A15,…` specifically means “just give me the column A values for whatever values match.”

I believe you want the first argument to be `=FILTER(A1:B15,…`